# Warning C4005 'identifier' : macro redefinition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit, preprocessor-directive

I want my application to work in win32 and x64 platform. I have added below code in header file but I am getting C4005 warning. How can I avoid this?

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define SIZEOF_ANALYSIS_INFO 168    
#endif
#ifdef _WIN64
#define SIZEOF_ANALYSIS_INFO 172
#endif
```

Comment: [`#elif`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The _WIN32 macro is always defined when compiling on Windows these days, even in 64 bit compiles.  You'll want to rearrange your code a bit:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
#define SIZEOF_ANALYSIS_INFO 172
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#define SIZEOF_ANALYSIS_INFO 168
#endif
```

If you're always compiling this with VC, you can just use `#else` in the middle.

Better yet would to be to use the `sizeof` operator with whatever struct is holding the analysis info, if possible.

Comment: Thanks @1201ProgramAlarm your solution is working perfectly.

Comment: *"_WIN32 macro is always defined"* on windows, not the case on *nix ;-)